# UK visitor visa application 2 years / 5 years and no visit done in current 6 Month visitor visa (2019)?

Tags: visas, uk

We (mother, father and daughter) have a UK visit visa 6 month till November 30 but we cannot visit.

Previously, my mother and father had visa and visited in Jan 2019. But this is my first visitor visa valid till November 2019. But in this visa we are busy and cannot visit.

Now I will apply for a 2 year visa or 5 year visa? And the fact that we didnt use this 6 month visa, can it have a negative impact on our new application,

should we apply for 2 year or 5 year as my father also works (age 65) and I also work (age 30 and unmarried) and father works in private sector. Or 5 year visa has very little chances?